# How to send a ListView item when clicked, to another page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am working with a ListView with multiple items listed, each with their own buy button. Right now the user can select the buy button on the item (car) they want, and it takes them to the BuyCars.aspx page, but nothing shows up for the selected item (car). I'm having trouble figuring out how to send the data when the user clicks buy on a certain car to the BuyCars.aspx total page.

I apologize for the amount of code, but this issue is driving me insane.

Here is my code. Thank you!

## Cars.aspx

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterBlaster024.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Cars.aspx.cs" Inherits="CarSales_REAL.WebForm2" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="div2" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
      <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" class="custom-class" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" DataKeyNames="CarID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="custom_class">
              <a href='/Shop/Order/<%# Eval("CarID") %>'>
                            <img src='/Images/<%# Eval("ImageCar") %>'
                                alt='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></a>
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>
                  <%# Eval("Name") %>
                </h3>
                <p><b>Price: <%# Eval("CarPrice", "{0:c}") %></b>
                  <br><br>
                  <%# Eval("Long_Description") %>
                </p>
              </div>
              <%--<div class="row">
                            <div class ="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-1">Quantity:</label>
                            </div>     
                                                                               
                        </div>--%>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="text-danger"
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity1" Display="Dynamic" 
                            ErrorMessage="Quantity is a required field." ValidationGroup='<%# ListView1.ClientID + "_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Quantity must range from 1 to 2." MaximumValue="2" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>--%>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <asp:Button ID="btnBuy" runat="server" Text="Buy Car" onclick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="btn" ValidationGroup='<%# ListView1.ClientID + "_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                      <asp:Button ID="btnCart" runat="server" Text="See Selected Car" PostBackUrl="~/BuyCars.aspx" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btn" />


                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="text-info col-sm-12"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
      <%--<div class="col-sm-3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity1" runat="server"                
                                CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>--%>
    </div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CarID], [Name], [Long_Description], [CarPrice], [ImageCar] FROM [Table] ORDER BY [Name]" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  </asp:Content>
```

## Cars.aspx.cs

```html
namespace CarSales_REAL
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Product selectedProduct;

        

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
            
            if (!IsPostBack) ListView1.DataBind();
            selectedProduct = this.GetSelectedProduct();
            

        }

        private Product GetSelectedProduct()
        {
            DataView productsTable = (DataView)
                SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            //productsTable.RowFilter = "CarID = '" + ListView1.SelectedValue + "'";
            DataRowView row = productsTable[1];

            Product p = new Product();
            p.CardID = row["CarID"].ToString();
            p.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
            //p.Short_Description = row["Short_Description"].ToString();
            p.Long_description = row["long_Description"].ToString();
            p.CarPrice = (decimal)row["CarPrice"];
            //p.ImageFile = row["ImageFile"].ToString();
            return p;
        }

        protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            
           
            
            
        }

        

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            Button btnBuy = (Button)sender;
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                CartItemList cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
                CartItem cartItem = cart[selectedProduct.CardID];

                if (cartItem == null)
                {
                    //cart.AddItem(selectedProduct,
                    //                Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity1.Text));
                }
                else
                {
                    //cartItem.AddQuantity(Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity1.Text));
                }
                Response.Redirect("BuyCars.aspx");

            }
        }

        protected void btnCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

## BuyCars.aspx

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterBlaster024.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="BuyCars.aspx.cs" Inherits="CarSales_REAL.WebForm3" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterBlaster024.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
    
</asp:Content>
    
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="div2" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><asp:ListBox ID="Cart1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:ListBox></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" 
                Text="Remove Item" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" CssClass="btn"/></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><asp:Button ID="btnEmpty" runat="server"
                    Text="Empty Cart" OnClick="btnEmpty_Click" CssClass="btn" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
                    CssClass="text-info col-sm-12"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server"
                        PostBackUrl="~/Cars.aspx" Text="Continue Shopping" CssClass="btn" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" Text="Check Out"  
                        onclick="btnCheckOut_Click" CssClass="btn" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>

    
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

## BuyCars.aspx.cs

```html
namespace CarSales_REAL
{
    
    
        public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            private CartItemList cart;

            
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                

                cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
                if (!IsPostBack)
                    this.DisplayCart();
            }

            private void DisplayCart()
            {

                Cart1.Items.Clear();
                CartItem item;

                for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
                {
                    item = cart[i];
                    Cart1.Items.Add(item.Display());
                }
            }

            protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (cart.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Cart1.SelectedIndex > -1)
                    

                    
                    {
                        cart.RemoveAt(Cart1.SelectedIndex);
                        this.DisplayCart();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = "Please select the item you want to remove.";
                    }
                }
            }

            protected void btnEmpty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (cart.Count > 0)
                {
                    cart.Clear();
                    Cart1.Items.Clear();
                }
            }

            protected void btnCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Sorry, that function hasn't been implemented yet.";
            }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you save the cart in the database during `cart.AddItem(` and `cartItem.AddQuantity(` also why are they commented so meaning they never do anything. Do you read from database with `CartItemList.GetCart();` ? if yes then the first part is your problem. You never save anything. a second problem would be if you do save it. Only 1 user can use it since you are loading the same cart for everybody.

Comment: I am so stupid and ignorant! That was the issue this whole time... I forgot to uncomment those out. Thank you so very much!